Understanding Linux 'top' command: Memory vs Swap display format confusion
Does the "avail Mem" value actually relate to physical memory rather than swap, despite being displayed on the swap line? I noticed there's a period at the end of the "swap used" column.


Related, but not a dupe: https://superuser.com/q/980820/11945

Yes you have it correct.  This confused me for a number of years.
Top's display of swap statistics needs only three columns out of the available four, while its display of memory statistics needs five.  That's why the "avail Mem" statistic has the word "Mem" in its label.  It clarifies that statistic is for memory even though it's on the line with the swap stats.  The other memory stats are on the line titled "Mem :" so they don't need the word "Mem" in their labels.

Yes, avail Mem in top is referring to physical memory, and does not include swap, despite how it is (confusingly) displayed to the right of the swap statistics.
Technically, this is the value of the MemAvailable kernel value (available in /proc/meminfo) and roughly approximates* the amount of free memory plus the values for buffers and cache. It's a representation of the amount of memory which is available to running processes without needing to swap out pages (but possibly by discarding pages which are cached)
MemAvailable is generally a more useful metric than MemFree (which top displays as free in the $unit Mem: section) because you generally want all of your memory doing something rather than being idle, and so the linux kernel will utilize otherwise unused RAM as a disk cache. The https://www.linuxatemyram.com site is often cited as an explanation of this mechanic.

* pedantic readers will note that avail in top is not as simple as free+buff/cach. The official kernel documentation defines MemAvailable as:
MemAvailable: An estimate of how much memory is available for starting new
              applications, without swapping. Calculated from MemFree,
              SReclaimable, the size of the file LRU lists, and the low
              watermarks in each zone.
              The estimate takes into account that the system needs some
              page cache to function well, and that not all reclaimable
              slab will be reclaimable, due to items being in use. The
              impact of those factors will vary from system to system.

